# assign row a count-number according to Value of on column R

Tags: r, count

I am looking for an elegant way to assign each row the number of times a certain value of a column has been occuring, example:

```
df1
Ch1    Year      
X1      2010
X1      2011
X1      2012
X2      2011
X2      2013
...
```

I want to add a row like this

```
df1
Ch1    Year      Count
X1      2010      1
X1      2011      2
X1      2012      3
X2      2011      1
X2      2013      2
...
```

now I know I can create a loop or work with unite/seperate.
Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is group_by sequence

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Ch1) %>%
   mutate(Count = row_number())
```

---

In `base R`, it can also be done with `sequence`

```
df1$Count <- sequence(table(df1$Ch1))
```